# flow panel with listview

Tags: c#, listview, runtime, flowpanel

I'm creating listviews in a flowpanel at run time which later will accept drag and dropped files. the reason being is i want these to act as folders so a user double clicks and gets a window displaying the contents.

i'm having difficulty setting up the events for my listviews as they are added.

how do i create some events (like MouseDoubleClick and DragDrop) dynamically for each added listview? can i create a single function for both of these events and have listview1, listview2, listviewX use it?

i have a button that is adding the listviews, which works fine. please advise, i apologize if this is too conceptual and not exact enough.

```
private void addNewWOButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListView newListView = new ListView();
            newListView.AllowDrop = true;
            flowPanel.Controls.Add(newListView);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to have the routine already created in your code:

```
private void listView_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  // do stuff
}

private void listView_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  // do stuff
}
```

and then in your routine, your wire it up:

```
private void addNewWOButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ListView newListView = new ListView();
  newListView.AllowDrop = true;
  newListView.DragDrop += listView_DragDrop;
  newListView.DragEnter += listView_DragEnter;

  flowPanel.Controls.Add(newListView);
}
```

You would have to check who the "sender" is if you need to know which ListView control is firing the event.

You can also just use a lambda function for simple things:

```
newListView.DragEnter += (s, de) => de.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
```

Comment: got it. never used that sender argument before today. now i have. thanks.

 `code`ListView thisListView = sender as ListView;
                    thisListView.Items.Add(file);

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to unwire the events with `-=` if you also remove the `ListView`s dynamically.

To answer the other half of your question, you can use a single handler for any event, from any source, that has the handler's signature.  In the body of the handler, you just have to check the `sender` argument to determine which control raised the event.

You need a way to tell one control from a different one of the same class, however.  One way to do this is to make sure to set the `Name` property on each control when you create it; *e.g.*, `newListView.Name = "FilesListView"`.

Then, before you do anything else in your event handler, check the sender.

```
private void listView_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
    ListView sendingListView = sender as ListView;
    if(sendingListView == null) {
        // Sender wasn't a ListView.  (But bear in mind it could be any class of
        // control that you've wired to this handler, so check those classes if
        // need be.)
        return;
    }
    switch(sendingListView.Name) {
        case "FilesListView":
            // do stuff for a dropped file
            break;
        case "TextListView":
            // do stuff for dropped text
            break;
        .....
    }  
}
```

Comment: aw nice thanks. nice thing about what i'm doing, i'm not going to allow the user to delete dynamically (yet). they'll have to wait for version 2.0.